# Spotify App: Facebook Wall Post

Tags: facebook, spotify

I have been looking through the Spotify API and on the web to try and find an answer, but haven't found what I need.  I need to post a message or a link onto someone's Facebook wall through a Spotify application.

Since Spotify runs using Facebook as a login mechanism, this should be possible, right?  Any advice on what calls to use to make this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found :

```
auth.showAuthenticationDialog(
    'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://my.domain.com&link=http://www.google.com&display=popup', //Facebook post popup
    'http://my.domain.com', //success URL
    {
        //Callback
        onSuccess : function(response) { },
        onFailure : function(error) { },
        onComplete : function() { }
    }
);
```

The parameter "redirect_uri" in the facebook pop-up URL must correspond to the 2nd parameter of the method auth.showAuthenticationDialog() if you want the pop-up to close properly after validating the post.

You can found the documention of auth.showAuthenticationDialog() here : http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/09321954e7.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet that Spotify does not provide this functionality. Think about it: Any post from a facebook app carries that App's name and icon with it throughout the site. Meaning that spotify app developers could post anything on Facebook with the spotify name and brand. That spells a nightmare.

So, given that logic, you'll have to get the user to authenticate your own facebook application as well, and post with Facebook's [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. However, you can create your own app and use that app id to post your own messages from the Spotify app. You can easily authenticate a Facebook user using the Auth model.

http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/09321954e7.html

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer, I actually found the method auth.showAuthenticationDialog() to open the popin to post on facebook via a Facebook app. But I didn't understand how to close it properly after the user validates. Actually, the window is redirected to the parameter 'redirect_uri' in the facebook url I give to the method "showAuthenticationDialog" which seems pretty logical...

Do you have any idea about how to close the pop-up ?